# Restangular PUT not appending the id in the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, restangular

I've got an AngularJS App using Restangular for persistence on top of a Rails 4 API.  I've run into a problem with my updates not working.

My code in the `routeProvider`:

```
when('/course/edit/:courseId', {
  controller: 'CourseEdit',
  templateUrl: '/assets/templates/course/form.html',
  resolve: {
    course: function(Restangular, $route) {
      return Restangular.one('courses', $route.current.params.courseId).get();
    }
  }
})
```

My **controller** function:

```
function CourseEdit($scope, $location, course) {
  $scope.course = course;
  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.course.put().then(function() {
      $location.path('/course/view/' + $scope.course.id);
    });
  };
}
```

The request for the PUT is being made to http://mysite.com/courses rather than `http://mysite.com/courses/id`

like I expected it to be, and I can't seem to figure out why.

The error that rails throws out is `'No route matches [PUT] "/courses"`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to figure it out by poking around at my set up a bit more.  I had copied some config for Restangular from a tutorial that I'd found, without really examining whether or not all pieces were necessary.

In my `config()`

```
RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
  id: '_id.$oid'
});
```

That doesn't match what my fields are in my API, and was the culprit for the problems that I was having.  I ended up removing that, leaving only the config for `setBaseUrl` and it started working again.

Hopefully this will help someone else out who's struggling from the same blindness that I was.